# redirect all request that targets a folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have to configure .htaccess to catch all request that pointed to the "/uploads/documents" folder's files and redirect into a PHP script. That script will decide the file is able to download or not.

I've created a file under the /uploads/documents/.htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

but it does not work for me, when http://myhost.com/uploads/documents/test.pdf was called it downloaded the pdf file instead of redirecting to the index.php

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it without htacces:**

Simply add an 'index.php' in that folder which contains:

```
header('location: ../somefile.php');
exit;
```

Comment: even the redirect is not working, so it won't runs index.php